# Loading configuration only once before a set of test cases

Tags: java, junit

I have a java package which contains all my test case classes. Each class contains a lot of test cases. Each class is loaded and run one by one by JUnit. However each of the classes contains common configuration code which is run again and again and initialised everytime each of the classes are run.
These initializations take a lot of time.

Is there some way to load these configuration changes first and then run the test case so that I do not need to load them everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit4 has @BeforeClass annotation.
Just do something like this:

```
public class TestClass {

  private static SomeConnection connection;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUp() {
    //do common setup
    connection = new SomeConnection();
  }

  @Test
  public void testSomething() { }

  @Test
  public void testSomethingElse() { }

  @AfterClass
  public static void tearDown() {
    //do teardown operations
    connection.close();
  }

}
```

Method marked with `@BeforeClass` will run only once. Just make sure you use JUnit4.

**Update:**
Also note, that it should be **static**, and as @ChristopheRoussy mentioned, you can use @AfterClass to destroy your common setup.

Comment: Also consider using @AfterClass

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `static` method that is run before the tests within the class are ran.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void ranOnlyOnce() {
     /*...*/
}
```

Moreover, if you want to run this once before *all* of your tests, then you should group your tests in a suite, and put this method in this class, and use JUnit to run the suite instead of the tests.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses(value = { Test1.class, ... , Testn.class })
public class AllTests {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeAllTests() {
         /*...*/
    }
}
```

Note that annotations can be used only in Junit 4+.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend grouping your tests into a testsuite and doing the initialization from the testsuite. There is a good discussion of the possibilities here http://www.xoriant.com/blog/software-testing-and-qa/using-customized-junit-testsuite-for-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possibilities. The first and easiest is to use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` as has been suggested by Matyas and jFrenetic. This is the easiest way to do it if none of the test classes share setup code.

If the classes share the same setup and teardown, look at using the TestRule, specifically the ExternalResource, which allows you to run code before and after each class. The difference between this and `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` is that it uses the same class, and therefore the code can be shared more easily. This can be done for example:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({A.class, B.class, C.class})
public class UsesExternalResource {
    public static Server myServer= new Server();

    @ClassRule
    public static ExternalResource resource= new ExternalResource() {
        @Override
        protected void before() throws Throwable {
            myServer.connect();
        };

        @Override
        protected void after() {
            myServer.disconnect();
        };
    };
}
```

This works in a test class as well, so you could have different, but shared setups for different classes.